# Remove element at given index

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala, I have an `Array[Int]` object called `elem`.

I would like to remove the element at index `k`.

I have tried this:

```
elem.filter(! _.equals(elem(k)))
```

However, this removes all elements which are equal to `elem(k)`.

How could I remove only the element at the index `k`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elem.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 != k).map(_._2)
```

If you have
`Array("a", "b", "c")` then `zipWithIndex` - converts into `Array((0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"))`

Answer (score 18):

For all collections (you can view `Array` as such) you can use the immutable `patch` method that returns a new collection:

```
val xs = Seq(6, 5, 4, 3)
// replace one element at index 2 by an empty seq:
xs.patch(2, Nil, 1)  // List(6, 5, 3)
```

If you want a mutable collection, you might want to look at `Buffer` instead of `Array`.

```
val ys = collection.mutable.Buffer(6, 5, 4, 3)
ys.remove(2)
ys // ArrayBuffer(6, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

A complementary way of achieving this would be by taking and dropping around the index:

```
val filteredElem = elem.take(k) ++ elem.drop(k+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `splitAt` as follows,

```
val (l,r) = xs.splitAt(k)
l ++ r.drop(1)
```

Also in a similar way to using `zipWithIndex`, we generate the range of indices and filter out that with value `k`, we can then extract the rest, like this,

```
(0 until xs.size).filter(_ != k).map(xs)
```

Using `collect`,

```
 (0 until xs.size).collect {
   case x if x != k => xs(x)
 }
```

Using a for comprehension,

```
for (i <- 0 until xs.size if i != k) yield xs(i)
```

A more general form where we have a set of indices to exclude, namely for

```
val exclude = Set(k,k+3)
for (i <- 0 until xs.size if !exclude(i)) yield xs(i)
```

we map indices not in `exclude`.